# Is there a way to easily inspect and debug nuget packages source code

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget

When I use Java's maven and gradle, I can easily download the source code for artifacts. This way I can easily inspect source code and even debug it. It is very useful, especially for libraries with poor documentation.

I'm using Xamarin Studio and would like to do this for nuget packages and Xamarin components.

For example, I would like to add the [sqlite-net component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net) to my project and be able to browse to its source files.

Comment: You'll have to download the source separately from the Sqlite site.  Beware that it is mostly C code (the .net assembly is just a wrapper), so rebuilding and unmanaged code debugging skills required.  And beware that it doesn't have the bug you're trying to fix.

Comment: I'm talking about the sqlite-net component's code which is pure C#. I don't want to debug the sqlite code itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could try .Net Reflector. I remember I had it a while ago and it allowed me to see source of some libraries. I can't remember if there was anything special about those libraries (debug mode or something).